# Primes ’n’ Digits

Tags: code-golf, primes, factoring

This has no practical purpose but it could be fun to golf.

## Challenge

Given a number *n*,

1. Count the amount of each digit in *n* and add 1 to each count
2. Take the prime factorization of *n*
3. Count the amount of each digit in the prime factorization of *n*, without including duplicate primes
4. Create a new list by multiplying together the respective elements of the lists from steps 1 and 3
5. Return the sum of that list

For example, 121 has two `1`s and a `2`, so you would get the following list from step 1:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 3 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

The prime factorization of 121 is 11<sup>2</sup>, which gives the following list for step 3:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Note how we did not count the exponent. These multiply together to get:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

And the sum of this list is 6.

## Test cases

```
1 -> 0
2 -> 2
3 -> 2
4 -> 1
5 -> 2
10 -> 2
13 -> 4
121 -> 6
```

## Notes

- [Standard loopholes](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/75524) are forbidden.
- Input and output can be in any reasonable format.
- You should leave ones (or zeros for step 3) in the list for digits that did not appear in the number.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution in bytes wins.

Comment: Does 667 (=23*29) make for two 2s, one 3, and one 9 in step 3?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yes.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 `232792560` -> `[2,1,4,2,1,2,2,2,1,2]` (step 1); `2*2*2*2*3*3*5*7*14*17*19` (step 2); so `[0,5,1,2,0,1,0,2,0,1]` (step 3); then `[0,5,4,4,0,2,0,4,0,2]` (Step 4); and hence should output `21`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan It would be nice if I could count. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 5 bytes

```
fS¢>O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/LfjQIjv////NzMwB)

```
f      list of prime factors (without duplicates) of the implicit input
S      characters, all of the digits
¢      count each of the characters in the implicit input
>      increase each of the counts
O      sum (implicit output)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>18</s>  17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 byte thanks to [caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing) & [H.PWiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71256/h-pwiz) (avoid pairing the two vectors)

```
DF‘ċÐ€⁵
ÆfQÇæ.Ç‘$
```

A monadic link taking a positive integer and returning a non-negative integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/F7VHDjCPdhyc8alrzqHEr1@G2tMDD7YeX6R1uB0qo/P//39DIEAAA)**

#### How?

```
DF‘ċÐ€⁵ - Link 1, digitalCount: number(s)    e.g. [13,17]
D       - to decimal list (vectorises)            [[1,3],[1,7]]
 F      - flatten                                 [1,3,1,7]
  ‘     - increment (vectorises)                  [2,4,2,8]
      ⁵ - literal ten                             10
    Ð€  - map across              (implicit range [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
   ċ    - count                                   [0,2,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0]

ÆfQÇæ.Ç‘$ - Main link: positive integer, n   e.g. 11999
        $ - last two links as a monad:
      Ç   -   call the last link (1) as a monad   [0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3]
       ‘  -   increment (vectorises)              [1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4]
Æf        - prime factorisation                   [13,13,71]
  Q       - deduplicate                           [13,17]
   Ç      - call the last link (1) as a monad     [0,2,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0]
    æ.    - dot product                           8
```

Comment: [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/F7VHDjCPdhyc8alrzqHEr1@G2tMDD7YenH24HiqsE////39DIEAA)

Comment: Or use dot product

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
ṾċÐ€ØD
ÆfQÇ×Ç‘$S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9qZWxsef//4bm@xIvDkOKCrMOYRArDhmZRw4fDl8OH4oCYJFP/UsW8w4figqxH//8xMjE)

Developed independently from and not exactly the same as [the other Jelly solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151631/75553).

**Explanation**

I'm gong to use `242` as an example input.

```
ṾċÐ€ØD     Helper link
Ṿ          Uneval. In this case, turns it's argument into a string. 
           242Ṿ → ['2','4','2']. [2,11] → ['2', ',', '1', '1']. The ',' won't end up doing anything.
    ØD     Digits: ['0','1',...,'9']
 ċÐ€       Count the occurrence of €ach digit in the result of Ṿ

ÆfQÇ×Ç‘$S  Main link. Argument 242
Æf         Prime factors that multiply to 242 → [2,11,11]
  Q        Unique elements → [2,11]
   Ç       Apply helper link to this list → [0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
     Ç‘$   Apply helper link to 242 then add 1 to each element → [1,1,3,1,2,1,1,1,1,1]
    ×      Multiply the two lists element-wise → [0,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        S  Sum of the product → 5
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>43</s> 41 bytes

```apl
⎕CY'dfns'
+/×/+/¨⎕D∘.=⍕¨(⎕D,r)(∪3pco r←⎕)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPdOSM1Ofv/o76pzpHqKWl5xepc2vqHp@tr6x9aARR0edQxQ8/2Ue/UQys0QFydIk2NRx2rjAuS8xWKHrVNAIppgkz5DzaGy5CLC8IwgjGMYQwTGMMUxjA0gLPgqgyNDAE)

**How?**

`r←⎕` - input into `r`

`3pco` - prime factors

`∪` - unique

`⎕D,r` - `r` prepended with `0-9`

`⍕¨` - format the factors and the prepended range

`⎕D∘.=` - cartesian comparison with every element of the string `0123456789`

`+/¨` - sum each row of the two tables formed

`×/` - multiply the two vectors left

`+/` - sum the last vector formed

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 44 bytes

```
Y_N_.aM,tT++o>aTa%o{a/:olPBo}$+y*Y_N JUQlM,t
```

Takes input from command-line argument. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/Mt4vXi/RV6ckRFs73y4xJFE1vzpR3yo/J8Apv1ZFu1ILqEDBKzQwB6jk////ugX/jYyNzC2NTM0MAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>136</s> 127 bytes

```python
lambda a:sum(''.join(u(a)).count(`i`)*-~`a`.count(`i`)for i in range(10))
u=lambda a:[`j`for j in range(2,a)if a%j<1>len(u(j))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY0xDsIwDAB3XuEF1UZQkYyI8hFAsoEWErVOG5KBha8HdQHW0@lufKVHUFum5lR6GS43Adk984BVVfvgFDMKUX0NWROyY1pt3iz8B7oQwYFTiKL3Fs2WaJGbb@vInmfF/xS7FnIdyNLvzaFv54cnOpcxOk0wobGGygc)

## Credits

- Reduced from 136 bytes to 127 by [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)

Comment: [127 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY0xDsIwDAB3XuEF1UZQkYyI8hFAsoEWErVOG5KBha8HdQHW0@lufKVHUFum5lR6GS43Adk984BVVfvgFDMKUX0NWROyY1pt3iz8B7oQwYFTiKL3Fs2WaJGbb@vInmfF/xS7FnIdyNLvzaFv54cnOpcxOk0wobGGygc)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Updated, thanks for showing me the use of `-~` I was always a bit confused on that. And I need to start remembering the `<1` thing.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can take a look through [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37553/59487) for `-~` and related stuff.